# How to create usercontrol dynamically?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

i have a flowlayoutpanel in my winform,
i want to add some button into the flowlayoutpanel when the form is loaded,
the number of button will depend on how many item(row) exist in my dataset

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIsoW.png)

```
    Private Sub temp_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
                Me.ItemInfoTableAdapter1.Fill(DataSet11.ItemInfo)
    End Sub

    Private Sub FlowLayoutPanel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles FlowLayoutPanel1.Paint
                Dim btn As New Button
                Dim table as datatable = Dataset11.Tables("ItemInfo")


              For 'i think this will need a looping, but i have no idea how to write'
                With btn
                   .Text = ?? 'text will be the itemName'
                   .Tag = ??  'tag will be the itemPrice'
                End With
                Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn)
              Next
    End Sub
```

i have no idea what to do next, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here aside from adding a control is *iterating* from a `datatable`. `Datatables` contain `DataRows`. So that is what you want to get to create the the buttons based on the content of your `datatable`.

Try this:

```
    Dim btn As New Button
    For Each drow As DataRow In table.Rows
        btn = New Button
        btn.Text = drow.Item("itemName").ToString
        btn.Tag = drow.Item("itemPrice").ToString
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn)
    Next
```

Also, you might take into consideration changing the event in which you are adding the controls in the `FlowLayoutPanel`. You can use a `Form_Load` event for example.

Comment: Note that .Tag is an object so you can store more complex data structures if you wish - a class object for example.